# Calling Control from another Form Gets Error: Method or Data member not Found

Tags: vba

I'm encountering error Method or data member not found when I compile my project. button control "btnViewUpdateRefresh" exists in other form.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Terminate()
Dim oSection As Word.Section
Dim oRange As Word.Range
Dim var

If Documents("PART V1.0.docm").ProtectionType <> wdNoProtection Then
    Documents("PART V1.0.docm").Unprotect "1234"
Else
End If

ThisDocument.Activate
ThisDocument.StoryRanges(wdMainTextStory).Delete

MainWindow.Show

Call MainWindow.btnViewUpdateRefresh_Click --> error points in here.

If Documents("PART V1.0.docm").ProtectionType <> wdNoProtection Then
Else
    Documents("PART V1.0.docm").Protect wdAllowOnlyFormFields, True, "1234"
End If
```

End Sub

Comment: Is `btnViewUpdateRefresh_Click` Private?

Comment: sir Tim Williams sir.. yes it is. thank you for your reply

Comment: oh my. so it should be Public not Private.. gosh why I didn't think of that... again.. Thank you so much Sir @TimWilliams :)